# Find Duplicate strings in an array and modify them

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I have a huge array of strings, here is a small portion of it:

```
let x = [
  'FireDisaster_03_', 
  'FireDisaster_03_', 
  'FireDisaster_03_', 
  'FireDisaster_05_', 
  'FireDisaster_05_', 
  'FireDisaster_07_', 
  'FireDisaster_07_', 
  'FireDisaster_07_', 
  'FireDisaster_07_', 
  'FireDisaster_08_', 
  'FireDisaster_08_', 
  'FireDisaster_08_'
]
```

I need to add sequential number to each duplicate string. Such that the result will look like:

```
[
  'FireDisaster_03_0', 
  'FireDisaster_03_1',  
  'FireDisaster_03_2', 
  'FireDisaster_05_0', 
  'FireDisaster_05_1', 
  'FireDisaster_07_0', 
  'FireDisaster_07_1', 
  'FireDisaster_07_2', 
  'FireDisaster_07_3', 
  'FireDisaster_08_0', 
  'FireDisaster_08_1', 
  'FireDisaster_08_2'
]
```

Please help me solve this

Thank you

Comment: And what are using to do this?

Comment: Well, its more machine learning purposes, there are many image files but they are not named properly, I was able to bring it up to what I have now but was unable to add a number for repeated names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce`. Also sorting the array before operation to compare only with previous element

```js
let x = ['FireDisaster_03_', 'FireDisaster_03_', 'FireDisaster_03_', 'FireDisaster_05_', 'FireDisaster_05_', 'FireDisaster_07_', 'FireDisaster_07_', 'FireDisaster_07_', 'FireDisaster_07_', 'FireDisaster_08_', 'FireDisaster_08_', 'FireDisaster_08_'].sort();
let newStrArray = x.reduce((accumulator, currentVal, index) => {
  // for the first element of the array no changes need to be done
  if (index === 0) {
    accumulator.push(`${currentVal}${index}`);
  } else {
    // check if the current element is same as the previous element from
    // the main array
    const prevVal = x[index - 1];
    if (prevVal === currentVal) {
      // if same then get the previous element from accumulator array
      const getPrevVal = accumulator[index - 1];
      // get the last character , convert to number and increase it by 1
      const num = parseInt(getPrevVal.charAt(getPrevVal.length - 1), 10) + 1;
      // push value to accumulator array
      accumulator.push(`${currentVal}${num}`)
    } else {
      // if previous and current element are not same then 
      // push current element in accumulator array
      accumulator.push(`${currentVal}0`)
    }
  }


  return accumulator;
}, []);
console.log(newStrArray)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take a object for the seen values and store the counter.

This approach uses a closure over `seen` with an IIFE ([immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)) and an expression which checks if the key exits in the object or not.

In the first case, it takes the value from the property and adds one; in the second case it takes zero as value for assigning to the property and at the same time this value is used to concat with the string.

```js
let x = ['FireDisaster_03_', 'FireDisaster_03_', 'FireDisaster_03_', 'FireDisaster_05_', 'FireDisaster_05_', 'FireDisaster_07_', 'FireDisaster_07_', 'FireDisaster_07_', 'FireDisaster_07_', 'FireDisaster_08_', 'FireDisaster_08_', 'FireDisaster_08_'],
    result = x.map(
        (seen => v => v + (seen[v] = v in seen ? seen[v] + 1 : 0))
        ({})
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function and `.map()` like this:

```js
let x = ['FireDisaster_03_', 'FireDisaster_03_', 'FireDisaster_03_', 'FireDisaster_05_', 'FireDisaster_05_', 'FireDisaster_07_', 'FireDisaster_07_', 'FireDisaster_07_', 'FireDisaster_07_', 'FireDisaster_08_', 'FireDisaster_08_', 'FireDisaster_08_']

x = x.map((c, i, a) =>
  a.indexOf(c) === i ? c + '0' : f(a.indexOf(c), c, i, a.slice(1), 1)
);

function f(ac, c, i, a, s) {
  return a.indexOf(c) === i - s ? c + (s - ac) : f(ac, c, i, a.slice(1), s + 1);
}

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
found = {}
x.forEach( (val, i) => {
    found[val] = (found[val]||0) +1;
    x[i] += found[val]-1;
})
```

If you don't mind starting with 1, can remove  last -1